# How to get value from a form element of type="button"

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have the following code within a form

```
<input type="button" name="nameofbutton" value="VALUE 1" onclick="javascript:if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {someSubmitFunction();}"/> 
<input type="button" name="nameofbutton" value="VALUE 2" onclick="javascript:if (confirm('Are you sure??')) {someSubmitFunction();}"/>
```

When the form is submitted, with classic ASP I try and use`Request.Form("nameofbutton")` but I get no value. Could anyone please explain why? if I change it to a button of type "submit", it works, but it means the form gets submitted twice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Janusz Jasinski: This works for me; you'll notice I purposely made the contents of the buttons `what ever`, when you submit the form the `value` attribute's contents will be shown. Save the code and test it out for yourself, it's a working sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<%
If UCase(Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")) = "POST" Then
    Response.Write "<p>nameofbutton: " & Request.Form("nameofbutton") & "</p>"
End If
%>

<form action="4367350.asp" method="post">
    <div>
        <button name="nameofbutton" value="VALUE 1" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { this.form.submit(); } else { return false; }">what ever 1</button>
        <button name="nameofbutton" value="VALUE 2" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { this.form.submit(); } else { return false; }">what ever 2</button>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using input buttons to submit?

```
<input type="submit" ... onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
```

if the `onclick` of a submit button (or better yet, the `onsubmit` of a form) returns false, then the submit is cancelled.

Comment: I want to run some JavaScript on the form (onSubmit in the form) and then use the function to submit the form. If I have the submit input, it will submit the form twice. 

However if I do not have the onSubmit in the form, the form will submit via the input and then via my function if I assign it onClick to the input field

Comment: Is there no way to get the value of the button?

Comment: You could pass the value of the button to your `someSubmitFunction`. eg: `onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?') someSubmitFunction(this.value);"` After that, you'd have to inject that value as a hidden field into the form before submitting it. Since the button is not doing the submitting (your function is), the value is not automatically included.